# How to write this script in unix?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, ksh

How can I write a script for finding the files created by a particular user ID in some locations and tar those files in the same location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example creating a tarball of all files belonging to the root user anywhere beneath the current directory:

```
find . -uid 0 -print0|xargs -0 tar cf files-of-root-user.tar
```

You would replace `-uid 0` with the id of the user you want to create the tar for.